# Sitecore Experience editor get data source

Tags: javascript, sitecore, sitecore8, experience-editor

I need to get the current component data source in experience editor, I've tried my best to hack it apart but can't seem to find the value or documentation on how to retrieve it.

If you click on a component => Edit component properties

This brings up a dialog box, I need the value of the "Data Source" field at run time, I can see the code inline that launches the dialog box, however it doesn't seem to make a request and I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve the data I need.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you need this details when running in Experience Editor mode or when the site is running for normal users? You can access the datasource item using `RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item`

Comment: @jammykam I'm looking for a way to retrieve this with javascript in experience editor

Comment: AFAIK, there is not way of retrieving this OOTB, but it's possible you could parse the JSON in the `<code>` block related to the component... You could programatically set some `data-*` attributes or javascript object yourself in EE mode.. that's what I would be looking at. Sorry don't have a concrete answer for you.

Comment: That's alright, more or less what I ended up doing, was just hoping to hack a way together to retrieve it but I tried for about 8 hours with no success, had to do it per template but oh well